# How to skip dates without values in plotly dash go.Scatter xaxes?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I want to show a diagram with measurement data above time (with ticks in milliseconds).
Since I combine two or more measurements, that where done with some minutes space in between, plotly shows the full date-axis, with a gap in between the measurement values.

This is the current code:

```
def getCrackWidthDiagram(list1, list2, title, xaxis_title, yaxis_title):
    figure = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(
        x=list1, y=list2, marker_color="rgb(165,0,0)", mode='markers', marker_size=2)],)
    figure.update_layout(
        go.Layout(
            title=title,
            xaxis={
                "tickformat": ".6f",
            },
            xaxis_title=xaxis_title,
            yaxis_title=yaxis_title
        ),
        margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=30, b=0),
    )
    figure.update_xaxes(
        tickformat="%H:%M:%S.%f\n%Y/%m/%d",  # Format to display microseconds
        dtick=60000, #timedifference in milisec (1min)
    )
    return figure
```

Resulting in this graph:
[This is the current figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz2Zy.png)

I tried to switch the xaxis type to "category", like recommended in another question, leading the xaxis to only show a single timestamp.

This is what I tried:

```
def getCrackWidthDiagram(list1, list2, title, xaxis_title, yaxis_title):
    figure = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(
        x=list1, y=list2, marker_color="rgb(165,0,0)", mode='markers', marker_size=2)],)
    figure.update_layout(
        go.Layout(
            title=title,
            xaxis={
                "tickformat": ".6f",
                "type":"category" #this is what I added
            },
            xaxis_title=xaxis_title,
            yaxis_title=yaxis_title
        ),
        margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=30, b=0),
    )
    figure.update_xaxes(
        tickformat="%H:%M:%S.%f\n%Y/%m/%d",  # Format to display microseconds
        dtick=60000, #timedifference in milisec (1min)
    )
    return figure
```

Resulting in this figure:

[figure with only one timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKSZc.png)

Comment: I haven't tried this as no data is presented. dtick and scale TimeSries formatting are not used, but a time series to string and axis type of category would produce the intended graph?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your tip! It worked, but now I have every single timestamp, that is with a frequency of 5 Hz too much. Is there a way to do something equal to dticks?

Comment: dtick is a function to make time series equally spaced, but your data is discontinuous data. It seems like a conflicting request.